# Neo4j is there a more efficient way for writing multiple where-contains?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a query and have a bunch of email providers that I want to search on.  Is there a more efficient way to write my where clause that just has a bunch of `contains`?

```
match (s:Sender)-[]-(r:Recipient)
where s.domain contains "gmail" OR s.domain contains "yahoo" OR s.domain contains "hotmail" OR s.domain contains "aol" 
return s,r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

Create a list of domain fragments and then see if any of them are contained in the scalar on your `Sender` node.

```
MATCH (s:Sender)-[]-(r:Recipient)
WHERE [dom_frag in ["gmail", "yahoo", "hotmail", "aol"] WHERE s.domain contains dom_frag]
RETURN s,r
```